# Out of $16:9$ ratio, if $16$ represents $100\%$ what percentage does $9$ represent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, percentages, ratio

Just like the title says,

> Out of a $16:9$ ratio, if $16$ represents $100\%$ what percentage does $9$ represent?

Comment: Please write what you tried

Comment: $100\% \frac {9}{16} = 56.25\%$?

Comment: $\frac 9{16} = \frac x{100}$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: If 16 is 100% then the 9 is x %. Divide both expressions: $9/16=x/100\%$. Solve for $x$ and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a simple proportion.
$$\frac{16}{100}=\frac9x$$
Cross multiply
$$16x=900$$
Simplify
$$x=\frac{225}{4}\;\text{or}\;x=56.25$$